# Output is stopped because of & (ampersand). I need to enclose each line of output in quotes? I think?

Tags: command-line, find

I use pushbullet to send a list of recently modified files to my phone each morning. I use Find and printf to clean the list and push it to a pushbulet script.

```
/home/user/scripts/pushbullet/pushbullet.sh "Synced: `find /mnt/1tb/tv/ /mnt/1tb/movies/ -type f -ctime -1 | wc -l`" "`find /mnt/1tb/tv/ /mnt/1tb/movies/ -type f -ctime -1 -printf "%f\n"`"
```

First it gets the count of modified files, and then a list of the modified files without the directory.

The problem is if the file name is `File&Cheese.mkv` the message sent to me stops at 'File' and nothing after the ampersand is sent. This is a problem with the pushbullet script.

**I think it would be easiest just to make sure that each line of the list that is output goes in quotation marks but I cannot work out how to do this.**

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get each filename in quotes by piping your `find` output to `while` and using `echo`

```
find ... |  while read line ; do echo \""$line"\" ; done
```

replace `find ...` with your whole `find` command.

The escaped quotes `\"` will print literal `"` around each line, but also quote the variable to prevent expansions.

Output will look like

```
"my file"
"another file"
"File&Cheese.mkv"
```

Comment: @Daisyqq most welcome! :)